# Is there a viewer control for XtraReports in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtrareport

DevExpress XtraReports has a predefined window for showing up the reports that is bundle with the report class, but I wonder if there is a viewer control like Active Reports has to show the report.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the PrintControl.